# android : issue with laying out components in tablelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

am new to android development. in the android app that am working on, am trying to display a person’s photo and his/her details as shown below. The details are fetched from database but, of enow, I have hardcoded. Am having issue with the layout. I used tableview layout (because grid layout is not supported in version 8 of android). ‘name’ & ‘country’ are in row 1 of the table. ‘age’, ‘city’, ‘status’ are in row 2.

I tried so relative & linear layouts (tried switching between them), in vain. Also , tried to follow several answers from stack overflow.

1.Why is there so much unused space to the right corner of the table view? Am trying to spread out the fields to the center of the table view with some gap to the sides (the top bar in the page) but it seems to gravitate towards the left as you can see (and so leaves so much spec to the right unused).

[image]

When I rotate, it becomes worse (everything floats to the left ; I want the fields to space out well and leave some gaps to the sides) as you can see here

[image]

Here is the layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MEFloorPlanDisplay" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="#666666"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="10dip"
                            android:text="NAME"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_1_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="10dip"
                            android:text="John"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="70dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="10dip"
                            android:text="COUNTRY"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_2_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="10dip"
                            android:text="AMERICA"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_weight="33"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="15dip"
                            android:text="AGE"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_3_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="0dip"
                            android:text="37"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_weight="33"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingTop="15dip"
                            android:text="CITY"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_4_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingTop="0dip"
                            android:text="CA"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_weight="34"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="15dip"
                            android:text="STATUS"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_5_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:maxLines="3"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="0dip"
                            android:text="SINGLE"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- image view code -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this codes..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MEFloorPlanDisplay" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="#666666"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="NAME"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_1_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="John"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="COUNTRY"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_2_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"                            
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="AMERICA"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="AGE"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_3_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="37"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="CITY"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_4_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="CA"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="STATUS"
                            android:textColor="#cccccc"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_5_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="SINGLE"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- image view code -->

</LinearLayout>
```

In Portrait

[image]

In Landscape

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid TableLayout. Use LinearLayouts inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: why do you ask to avoid TableLayout? isn't it a natural fit for such a situation?

Comment: RelativeLayout is better suited for multiple devices. I also heard TableLayout is deprecated in API level 14 and later, but I am not sure. But only thing sure is, RelativeLayout is better suited for multiple screens. It is also easier to manipulate when properly done.